# Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() gets files from phone memory

Tags: android, mp3, android-sdcard, internal-storage

I used `list.getPlayList(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get songs from sdcard, but unfortunately if phone has both "Internal phone memory and external sd card" it reads file only from phone memory,but I want from both to be added into single list to get the Mp3 files.

If there is any code, please provide or any links. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have mounted the sdcard? Do you have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission? Do you have any error? Add more code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct filesystem access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on most Android devices.

AFAIK, most media players do not work with the filesystem anyway. They use `MediaStore`, which contains an index of all files reachable by the system, including those on removable storage. You can use the `Uri` values that you get from `MediaStore` with `MediaPlayer` via [one of its `create()` methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri%29).